# The use of the definite article with proper nouns

Tags: articles

While accepting the destination argument for roads, why does the same conceit occur with countries? For example The Gambia, The Lebanon or The Argentine.

Comment: Actually, "Ask a new question" is overkill. Just edit this one to explain why the earlier question is deficient.

Comment: To pick a nit: I don't think anyone in the Anglosphere _does_ call it The Argentine any more. Or The Lebanon.